# How do I find out why JVM ignores kill -15 (SIGTERM) on linux?

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I am doing `kill -15 <PID>` on my working jvm and it seems completely ignored.

The invironment is:

- Linux 2.6 kernel
- jdk 1.6.0_20-x86-64

There are no references to `sun.misc.SignalHandler` in the project. The only (quite lame) clue I have is call to `AbstractApplicationContext.registerShutdownHook()` in main. JVM startup args do not contain anything related to signal handling.

There is nothing in logs (DEBUG level) and nothing printed out to stdout in reaction to `kill -15`.

How do I find out what causes ignoring of SIGTERM?

Answer (score 2):

> Normally, Signals 1 (SIGHUP), 2 (SIGINT), 4 (SIGILL), 7 (SIGBUS), 8
>   (SIGFPE), 11 (SIGSEGV), and 15 (SIGTERM) on JVM threads cause the JVM
>   to shut down; therefore, an application signal handler should not
>   attempt to recover from these unless it no longer requires the JVM.

Since your jvm doesn't exit, you may need to check whether there is:

1. Any use of [Runtime.addShutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)
2. Existence of the -Xrs option on JVM startup
3. Any use of sun.misc.SignalHandler.

Here is the AbstractApplicationContext.registerShutdownHook() in Spring source code.

```
public void registerShutdownHook() {
if (this.shutdownHook == null) {
        // No shutdown hook registered yet.
    this.shutdownHook = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        doClose();
        }
    };
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(this.shutdownHook);
}
}
```

Comment: The only hook usage is in spring ApplicationContext. Is it possible, that spring shutdown procedure prevents jvm from closing?

Comment: Yes, it calls the Runtime.addShutdownHook. Code added.